# Arcgis in Python: Color change on each execution. How to set fill color?

Tags: python, colors, arcgis

I want to draw a polygon in a map with a specific color. After reading the documentation in: 
https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.geometry.html 
, I'm not able to select the correct fill color. In fact, with the same code, the color changes in every single execution.

Here is some example code:

```
import arcgis
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.geometry import Geometry, Point, Polyline
from arcgis.mapping import create_symbol

gis = GIS()
map1 = gis.map(location=(39.456727, -0.352371), zoomlevel=15)
map1.basemap = "osm"


geom = Geometry({'spatialReference': {'latestWkid': 4326,
    'wkid': 4326},
    'rings': [
    [
            [-0.3524, 39.4566],
            [-0.3524, 39.4568],
            [-0.3522, 39.4568],
            [-0.3522, 39.4566],
            [-0.3524, 39.4566],
        ]
    ]
})
symbol = create_symbol(geometry_type='polygon', colors=[0, 255, 0])  # green

map1.draw(geom, symbol=symbol)
map1.export_to_html("test.html")
```

If I execute this and I open `test.html` with my browser, I can see:
[image]

If I execute the same code again and I open `test.html`, color has changed magically:
[image]

So, 2 questions:
1) Why is the colour changing on each execution?
2) How can I set the correct colour? I'm setting the colour to `[0, 255, 0]` but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correctly set the color of regions and points, I found that you can add a fourth parameter in `colors` argument with alpha channel:

```
symbol = create_symbol(geometry_type='polygon', colors=[0, 255, 0, 255])  # green
```

According with the documentation in https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.mapping.html the alpha value should be in range 0-1, but this should be an error, cause it only works if you put values in the range 0-255.

If you don't add alpha channel, `colors` argument is not considered as valid, and a random value is asigned to it. This is what makes the color change on every execution